# Dockable Toolbar

Tags: wpf, toolbar, dockable

I have an area in my application that contains toolbar, my toolbar is consist of movable canvas, that I can drag and drop it anywhere, what I want to do is to restrict the user and not allow the toolbar to be moved out of this area,
and make it dockable so I can dock it to the left, right, top and bottom of this specified area,

can anyone help me in this case?

bellow snapshot show the toolbar is highlighted by  red and the restricted area is highlighted by black this area the user can't move the toolbar out

[Here is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH8vD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can **reset** the toolbar's position after a drag operation is completed.

First get the toolbar's coordinate which is relative to the `Canvas`, then translate it to coordinate relative to the `bound` (black area).

You can then calculate how close the toolbar's center is from each edge of the `bound`. If the distance is lower than a defined value, move the toolbar to the edge (to dock it), you need to rotate the toolbar 90 degrees if you dock it to the left and right edges.

Something like this.